# How to use useMemo with an external API?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7, react-usememo

I'm working with `react-table` library for filtering and pagination. I am requesting data from a custom API using `Node` and rendering it using `useTable` hook from `react-table`. The documentation for `react-table` says the table data should be memoized, so I use the `useMemo` hook. The code is as shown:

```
  const data = React.useMemo(() => {
    axios.get("/custom/api/endpoint")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;   //Returns an array of objects
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err");
      });
  }, []);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at accessRowsForColumn (useTable.js:591)
    at useTable.js:195
    .
    .
```

Can anyone help me figure this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are memoizing the promise that axios creates. Instead make the call with `useEffect()`, and set the state. Unless you'll set the state again, the data would not change:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); // use an empty array as initial value

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/custom/api/endpoint")
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data); // set the state
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err");
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: useEffect is not memoization. useEffect is the act of comparing equality & recalculating a page although not caching. useMemo is for caching.

Comment: @JackieSantana "useEffect is not memoization" - indeed it's not, and it's also not the right tool for this problem. That's why the solution is to use `useEffect` for this case. Now days, you'll probably want to use one of the suspense based solutions (I like SWR).

Answer (score 0):

You're using this arrow function inside the `useMemo` call.

```
() => {
    axios.get("/custom/api/endpoint")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;   //Returns an array of objects
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err");
      });
  }
```

And it returns `undefined`. It's because `axios.get` returns a `Promise` and you're not assigning it to anything and your arrow function implicitly returns `undefined` as it doesn't have an explicit `return` statement.

Try this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/custom/api/endpoint")
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err");
    });
}, []);
```

Here `useEffect` is called after the initial render of the component, which calls `axios.get`. It is an async function so the `useEffect` call immediately returns after calling it. When the `axios.get` async call succeeds it calls the arrow function within the `then` call which assigns the data from the response to the `data` state variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a promise and not returning it, so the code is not waiting for the promise to resolve. Try with async await syntax, which is easier to visualize the flow.

```
  const data = React.useMemo(async () => {
    
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/custom/api/endpoint") 
        return res.data
      } catch(err) {
        throw err
      }
 
  }, []);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to do an async call within `useMemo`. From React documentation: "Remember that the function passed to useMemo runs during rendering. Don’t do anything there that you wouldn’t normally do while rendering. For example, side effects belong in useEffect, not useMemo."

Answer (score 0):

These solutions not succesful need for me, because I structured my pattern for project. My data request with redux dispatch (so redux-thunk) actually I used redux-toolkit for fast development.

I solved like this;

```
function Table ({ columns, data }) {
    // ...
    return /* standart react-table basic component */
}

function MyTable(props) {
  const columns = useMemo(() => props.columns, [props.columns]);
  const data = useMemo(() => props.data, [props.data]);

  return <Table columns={columns} data={data} />;
}

const PageListTable = () => {
    // ...
    const columns = [...]; // static variable

    useEffect(
      async () => {
        const payload = {};

        // some codes

        dispatch(getAllData(payload));
      },
      [activeId, isAuth] // listen from with useSelector
    );

    // some codes..

    return (
        {/* ..... */}

        <HOC.Async status={loading}>
            <MyTable
                columns={columns}
                data={getAllDataState.data}
            />
        </HOC.Async>

        {/* ..... */}
    );
}
```

My package.json specs like this;

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.4",
"react-table": "^7.7.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
```